# Crystal 2011 - Convert Ticks to Time

Tags: crystal-reports

I've got a Crystal Report (2011) that uses a Stored Procedure to display some data.  One of the fields is TimeSpent (bigint) and it holds the number of Ticks in a TimeSpan (in C#, we pass TimeSpan.Ticks to the DB to be stored).

Obviously on my report I wouldn't want to show this, so I am wondering how I can convert ticks to read `dd:hh:mm:ss`, e.g. `01:05:58:25` for `1 day, 5 hours, 58 minutes and 29 seconds`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tick is 100 nanoseconds, or 10 million ticks per second. So first convert to seconds
 `numbervar span := {field.ticks}/10000000;`

From there, just break the seconds down into time pieces (This snippet is from [tek-tips](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3543)):

```
numbervar days;
numberVar hrs;
numberVar min;
numberVar sec;
stringVar ddhhmmss;
days:= Truncate(Truncate(Truncate(span/60)/60)/24);
hrs := Remainder(Truncate(Truncate(span/60)/60),24);
min := Remainder(Truncate(span/60),60);
sec := Remainder(span,60);

ddhhmmss := totext(days,0,"") + ":" + totext(hrs,"00") + ":" + totext(min,"00") + ":" + totext(sec,"00");

ddhhmmss
```

Comment: Awesome.....I had the conversion from ticks to seconds but the rest I was really lost on.  This works like a charm, thanks a bunch!